# smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped

Tags: networking, pi-2

I DDoS'ed my pi as part of a stress test using 2 laptops, fully saturating the 150 Mbps LAN interface on it. Less than an hour later, I found out that the pi doesn't respond to the ping flood and TCP flood anymore. I double checked and saw that the interface doesn't work until I restarted the networking service. When I checked `dmesg` (before restarting networking), I found a lot of these:

`smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped`

Anyone know what this is? Is this normal? I've Googled around and it seems that people mostly encounter a `kevent 2` instead of this `kevent 0`. That's why I couldn't find any info.

I didn't touch any of the networking stuff except when I set a static IP address. All is well when network activity isn't as flooded as this.

Stable overclock: 1000MHz ARM, 500MHz core, 450MHz SDRAM, 4 overvolt, Heatsink and fan on SOC and LAN chips

Comment: I get this a lot now when trying to pull docker images running ubuntu server 16 on my Pi3. What did you do to fix it?

Comment: @Kendall I didn't do anything. It happens when there's way too much traffic. On the link in the answer, at line 450, is where the error comes from. The conditions (`if (!schedule_work` and `if (net_ratelimit())`) tell why this happens. The best action, I think, is to simply free up some resources to let the kernel handle network traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the kernel couldn't handle it, based on the source code.

[usbnet.c on Github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/74328c7da3924f856cb986509e505b414939060d/drivers/net/usb/usbnet.c)